# ggplot2: geom_smooth colour with scale_colour_brewer

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, colorbrewer

I have created a simple graph using geom_smooth:

```
test.dat <- data.frame(matrix(c(runif(20, 0, 20)), 10, 2))
names(test.dat) <- c("x", "y")

test.plot <- ggplot(test.dat, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + 
                    geom_smooth(method="loess")
```

The line that is produced is by default blue. I can change it manually to a given colour by adding this:

```
test.plot + geom_smooth(method="loess", colour="black")
```

However, I would like to base the colour choice on a palette that I have been using for a series of plots. Normally, this would be achieved by adding the respective line:

```
scale_colour_brewer(type = "div", palette = "Spectral")
```

Yet, this does not have any effect (nor does using scale_fill_brewer instead). I have found some discussion on the behaviour of geom_smooth with colour [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/498), but no apparent fix for this particular problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
test.plot + 
  geom_smooth(aes(colour=TRUE), method="loess") + 
  scale_colour_brewer(type = "div", palette = "Spectral")
```

The key thing is to use `colour` inside the `mapping` argument to `geom_smooth` (the `aes` part).  It doesn't matter what value you use, it just has to be distinct from whatever other values you're using to specify other line colors in the graph.

Here is a fuller example:

```
set.seed(1)
test.dat <- data.frame(
  x=runif(20), y=runif(20), 
  z=sample(letters[1:2], 20, rep=T)
)

ggplot(test.dat, aes(x, y, colour=z)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(colour="d"), method="loess") +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_brewer(type = "div", palette = "Spectral")
```

[image]

Notice how we can get `geom_smooth` to participate in the colour scale by adding a new distinct value ('d') to the existing colour values ('a', 'b').  Ggplot collects all the values that are assigned to the `colour` **aesthetic mapping** (in this case, `unique(c(test.dat$z, "d"))`), and allocates colors from the color scale to them.

Comment: Thanks, that is brilliant. Hadn't seen this 'colour=TRUE' way of putting something in the aes before; now I see how that had me stumped. Thanks again!

Comment: @simoncolumbus, if this answers your question, please consider checking it off as answered.